# How does a pushout and an exact sequence of modules give another exact sequence?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, exact-sequence, diagram-chasing

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913343/pushout-modules-short-exact-sequences) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3653920/short-exact-sequence-and-pushout), it has been asked how an exact sequence of modules $0 \to K \to A \to F \to 0$ and the pushout of $P \leftarrow K \to A$ give rise to a second exact sequence, namely a commutative diagram with both lines exact :
$$\begin{matrix}0&\to&K&\to&A&\to&F&\to&0\\&&\downarrow&&\downarrow&&\downarrow\\0&\to&P&\to&U&\to&F&\to&0\end{matrix}$$

I understand how we get the injectivity of $P\to U$ and the surjectivity of $U \to F$, but both answers are unclear on why $\mathrm{Ker}(U \to F) = \mathrm{Im}(P \to U)$.

If I understand somewhat correctly, we use the pushout property on $A \to F$ and $0 : P \to F$ to get a unique $v : U \to F$ verifying $v \circ (A \to U) = (A \to F)$ and $v \circ (P \to U) = 0$.
But I feel like there is no reason for $v$ to be the $U \to F$ morphism of the diagram.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You have to define where the second row comes from.  You're right, it should come from the universal property applied to the given map $A \to F$ and the zero map $P \to F$.  That *defines* the second row.  It is now clear that the image of $P \to U$ is contained in the kernel of $U \to F$ because that composite is $0$.  You just need the second inclusion.

Comment: I knew I was tired and was asking a non-question. Thanks a lot for your answer. But in the first link, the second row is *already* given to us. I guess the result is false if $U \to F$ can be chosen freely ?

Comment: Correct.  It cannot be true for ANY second row.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will try to find a counterexample to kill any remaining doubt in my head. :)